# Javascript replace does not replace

Tags: javascript, regex

The pattern in this code does not replace the parenthesis. I've also tried "/(|)/g".

```
var re = "/[^a-z]/g",
   txt = navsel.options[i].text.split(" ")[0], // here I get the text from a select and I split it.
   // What I expect is strings like "(en)" , "(el)" etc
   txt = txt.replace(re," ")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your input text and what are you expecting the output to be ?

Comment: edited, sorry I didn't specify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is a string, this will try to replace that exact string.  Regex objects don't have quotes around them, just the delimiters.  Try it like this:

```
var re = /[^a-z]/g,
   txt = navsel.options[i].text.split(" ")[0], // here I get the text from a select and I split it.
   txt = txt.replace(re," ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you prefer strings (and a more explicit type):

```
var re = new RegExp("[^a-z]", "g")
```